# c++: how to create a variadic sequence from struct members

Tags: c++11, templates

Suppose I have a templated class that is supposed to be called like this:

```
struct mystruct
{
   int    member1;
   long   member2;
   string member3;
};
```

Now I want to create a `boost::mpl::vector` that will effectively contain types of all the members in the struct (preferably in the same order):

```
using membervector1 = boost::mpl::vector<int, long, string>;
```

Of course I want the syntax to templated with respect to my struct, like this:

```
using membervector2 = some_smart_template<mystruct>;
static_assert(std::is_same<membervector1, membervector2>::value);
```

Comment: Until we get static reflection, you'll have to use something like [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html).

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` requires repeating all the struct members. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ static reflaction can be implemented in C++14 aready.

[Magic get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) almost does what you want, except that it's tuple, not mpl::vector, but I think it is not a big issue to get mpl::vector from tuple.

See [presentation slides with explaination](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CppCon/CppCon2016/master/Presentations/C%2B%2B14%20Reflections%20Without%20Macros%2C%20Markup%20nor%20External%20Tooling/C%2B%2B14%20Reflections%20Without%20Macros%2C%20Markup%20nor%20External%20Tooling%20-%20Antony%20Polukhin%20-%20CppCon%202016.pdf).

Comment: Good enough! Thanks!